# XCode Product > Analyze results

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm getting some unusual responses from the Produce > Analyze option in Xcode 4 that don't seem to make any sense to me. For example, I've always been taught to release instance variables in the `dealloc` method, but Analyze gives me this:

```
- (void)dealloc {
   [self.fileName release];
 //Incorrect decrement of the reference count of an object that is not owned at this point by the caller
```

Very confusing, can anyone shed some light on this one?

The property looks like this:

```
  @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * fileName;
```

Comment: do you ever actually assign a value to that ivar?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Confusing wording, but correct, error message.

When you do:

```
[self.foo release];
```

That can easily produce a dangling reference for the instance variable backing the `foo` property.  I.e. as far as the compiler is concerned, there is no `retain` that said `release` is balancing.

Either do:

```
[fooIVar release];
```

(Assuming `@synthesize foo = fooIVar;`)

Or:

```
self.foo = nil;
```

Comment: Why are you writing `fooIVar` when the name of the ivar is `foo` ?

Comment: We don't know what the ivar is actually named as the OP didn't post the `@synthesize`.... thus, a bit of free-wheelin' on the ivar name to label it for what it is, regardless of reality.

Answer (score 1):

The code should read:

```
[fileName release]
```

I get the same error if I add `self`.

Also do not forget to add

```
 [super dealloc];
```